# Match a Variable to Other Dataset Based using Multiple Overlapping Variables

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two data sets with some overlapping variables. One dataset is basically a subset of the other but needs an additional variable added based on some of the overlapping variables. For example

```
varA <- c(rep(c("a","b"), each=5))
blah <- c(11:20)
varB <- c(1:10)
speed <- rnorm(10)
dataset1 <- data.frame(varA,blah,varB,speed)


varA.2 <- c("a","a","b","b")
varB.2 <- c(2,10,11,7)
speed.2 <- rep(NA, 4)
dataset2 <- data.frame(varA.2, varB.2, speed.2)
dataset2
```

I would like the "speed.2" variable to contain the speed values for the lines where varA and varB are matching between the two sets.

I've tried something with "merge" but am having issues.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be:

```
colnames(dataset2) <- gsub("\\..*","", colnames(dataset2))
library(dplyr)
left_join(dataset2[,-3],dataset1[,-2])
#    Joining by: c("varA", "varB")
#   varA varB      speed
#1    a    2 -1.3243815
#2    a   10         NA
#3    b   11         NA
#4    b    7 -0.6026936
```

Or without changing the column names.

```
 merge(dataset1[,-2],dataset2[,-3], by.x=c("varA","varB"), by.y=c("varA.2", "varB.2"), all.y=TRUE)
 #  varA varB      speed
# 1    a    2 -0.6797753
# 2    a   10         NA
# 3    b    7 -2.1838454
# 4    b   11         NA
```

Values in speed differ as the example was without using `set.seed()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'match' function for "where varA and varB are matching"

```
dataset2$speed.2 = dataset1[match(paste(dataset2$varA.2,dataset2$varB.2),
                               paste(dataset1$varA, dataset1$varB)),]$speed
dataset2
  varA.2 varB.2   speed.2
1      a      2 0.3917783
2      a     10        NA
3      b     11        NA
4      b      7 1.3265439
>
```